# react: Need help understanding state change and render

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs.

I am trying to understand the relationship between updating the state of a component and the render function.

Below is my component class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {cellValue : "empty"};
  }

  fillCell = (player) => {
    if(player == 'x') {
      this.setState({cellValue: "x"});
    } else if(player == 'o') {
      this.setState({cellValue: "o"});
    }
  } 

  render() {
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className="cell"></div>;
  }
}

export default Cell;
```

When the webpage is first launched, the `<div>` element uses the styling of the css class `cell`. I have the css definition created in another file. When the `<div>` is clicked, `fillCell` function is  called. Inside that function, I am changing the state with `setState`.

This is my thought process, after I change the state, I want to change the appearance of the `<div>` possibly by changing the `className` to another CSS class that I will define. But I am stuck here. How do I 're-render' the `div` element ?

Can I possibly write code like the below ?

```
fillCell = (player) => {
  if(player == 'x') {
    this.setState({cellValue: "x"});
    renderCellWithNewCSS(); 
  } else if(player == 'o') {
    this.setState({cellValue: "o"});
  }
}
```

This does not seem to be logical as there is already a function called `render()` inside the code... Do I change this line of code then? :

```
render() {
  return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className="cell"></div>;
}
```

But I am not sure how to modify this line, can I possibly add a parameter to this function ?

Any guidance will help alot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> But I am stuck here. How do I 're-render' the div element?

ReactJS automatically re-renders changed objects after calling the `setState()` function.

In your render function, you want to add the class based on the state.

```
render() {
  if (this.state.cellValue !== 'empty') {
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className="cell filled"></div>;
  } else {
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className="cell"></div>;
  }
}
```

Or the cleaner method, like @Ramjan suggested.

```
render() {
  const divClass = (this.state.cellValue !== 'empty' ? "cell filled" : "cell");
  return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className={divClass}></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a state is changed, `render` is called automatically. You just have to write a condition in the `render` method to change the class name based on the current state.
For example -

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cellValue: "empty" };
  }

  fillCell = (player) => {
    if (player == 'x') {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "x" });

    } else if (player == 'o') {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "o" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { cellValue } = this.state;
    const divClass = cellValue === 'x' ? 'xClassName' : 'oClassName';
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className={divClass}></div>;
  }

}
export default Cell;
```

This will re-render your `div` with new className after `fillCell` function changes the state.
Although your `fillCell` function is always receiving `x` right now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the state is changed, render() is called automatically

so you don't have to re-render it yourself

in your case, you just have to apply the className based on some value in state

Here I have made a function that returns a string that is to be used as className

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cellValue: "empty" };
  }

  fillCell = player => {
    if (player == "x") {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "x" });
    } else if (player == "o") {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "o" });
    }
  };

  getClass = () => {
    const class1 = "some-stlye";
    const class2 = "some-other-style";

    if (this.state.cellValue === "x") {
      return class1;
    } else if (this.state.cellValue === "o") {
      return class2;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell("x")} className={getClass()}></div>;
  }
}
export default Cell;
```

Note that i have called the getClass, not just gave its reference, so it runs whenever the render is called and return a string which will be used as className

but making a function is not necessary
so you also put the code directly in render() like so:

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cellValue: "empty" };
  }

  fillCell = player => {
    if (player == "x") {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "x" });
    } else if (player == "o") {
      this.setState({ cellValue: "o" });
    }
  };


  render() {
    const class1 = "some-style";
    const class2 = "some-other-style";
    let applyThisClass = null;

    if (this.state.cellValue === "x") {
        applyThisClass =  class1;
    } else if (this.state.cellValue === "o") {
        applyThisClass =  class2;
    }

    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell("x")} className={applyThisClass}></div>;
  }
}
export default Cell;
```

Note: you can also shorten it like so :

```
  render() {
    const class1 = "some-style";
    const class2 = "some-other-style";
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell("x")} className={this.state.cellValue === "x" ? class1 : class2}></div>;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use your state inside render function and it will re-render automatically when state is changed. define your class name according to state something like that:

```
render() {
    let className = ""
    if (this.state.cellValue == 'empty') { 
      className = "your-class-name-for-empty" 
    else if (this.state.cellValue == 'x') {
      className = "your-class-name-for-x"
    else if (this.state.cellValue == 'y') {
      className = "your-class-name-for-y"
    }
    return <div onClick={() => this.fillCell('x')} className={className}></div>;
}
```